# Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library openssl

Tags: php, laravel, homebrew

When I tried to run `composer install` or `php artisan serve` the following error is prompted to me

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.9/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll'
>   - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.9/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

When I tried to access that file, I can't find it. For the record, I installed PHP with homebrew. please help me a way to find solution

Comment: The error message ("image not found") means the library isn't on your system. The odd thing is that you're referring to a DLL on a Mac. Your php.ini probably should refer to a .so file instead of a .dll.

Comment: Arr, I see. my bad. It's true that I should point out of .so instead of .dll.  I uncomment open_ssl without realizing it.  But I think php.ini seem strange coz I don't see any comments of .so file